# Struggling with Logic in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I need some help with T-SQL.

I can't use loops, cursors, etc. This is because I need high performance.

I would be very grateful if you may help me.

**Here is my problem:**

I have a table called `__tt_Freight_Product` which has the following columns:

```
dt_reference_date, id_contract, qtt_terminal_loaded
```

And a table called `Product` which has the following columns:

```
dt_reference_date, id_contract, id_fixing, qtt_fixing, qtt_terminal
```

There are NO foreign key between them, yet `id_contract` and `dt_reference_date` are supposed to be the same.

**Example data in `__tt_Freight_Product`:**

```
('2015-02-25', '0000006-t12', 200000)
('2015-02-26', '0000006-t12', 200000)
('2015-02-28', '0000006-t12', 100000)
```

That data means that 200,000 TONS was loaded on contract '0000006-t12' into terminal on '2015-02-25', and so on

**Example data in `Product`:**

```
('2015-02-24', '0000006-t12', 1, 300000, 0)
('2015-02-25', '0000006-t12', 1, 300000, 0)
('2015-02-26', '0000006-t12', 1, 300000, 0)
('2015-02-27', '0000006-t12', 1, 300000, 0)
('2015-02-28', '0000006-t12', 1, 300000, 0)
('2015-02-29', '0000006-t12', 1, 300000, 0)
('2015-02-24', '0000006-t12', 2, 200000, 0)
('2015-02-25', '0000006-t12', 2, 200000, 0)
('2015-02-26', '0000006-t12', 2, 200000, 0)
('2015-02-27', '0000006-t12', 2, 200000, 0)
('2015-02-28', '0000006-t12', 2, 200000, 0)
('2015-02-29', '0000006-t12', 2, 200000, 0)
```

What I need to accomplish is to split the loaded volumes that are on `__tt_Freight_Product` into the `Product` table, per `dt_reference_date/id_contract/id_fixing`. That split volume will be updated on the `Product` table.

It's kinda we had to divide the volume per "id_fixing".

**So, considering the example data on __tt_Freight_Product we will update:**

dt_reference_date: '2015-02-24'

Nothing will be updated as the cargo loaded just con 25th

**dt_reference_date:** '2015-02-25'

qtt_terminal of id_fixing "1" will be updated to 200,000

qtt_terminal of id_fixing "2" won't change

**dt_reference_date:** '2015-02-26'

qtt_terminal of id_fixing "1" will be updated to 300,000

qtt_terminal of id_fixing "2" will be updated to 100,000

**dt_reference_date:** '2015-02-27'

qtt_terminal of id_fixing "1" will be updated to 300,000, as we had cargo on the previous day and no loaded cargo on 27th OR considering we already have id_fixing '1' "*full allocated*"

qtt_terminal of id_fixing "2" will be updated to 100,000, as we had cargo on the previous day and no loaded cargo on 27th

**dt_reference_date:** '2015-02-28'

qtt_terminal of id_fixing "1" will be updated to 300,000, as we had cargo on the previous day and no loaded cargo on 27th OR considering we already have id_fixing '1' "*full allocated*"

qtt_terminal of id_fixing "2" will be updated to 200,000

**dt_reference_date:** '2015-02-29'

qtt_terminal of id_fixing "1" will be updated to 300,000, as we had cargo on the previous day and no loaded cargo on 29th OR considering we already have id_fixing '1' "*full allocated*"

qtt_terminal of id_fixing "2" will be updated to 200,000, as we had cargo on the previous day and no loaded cargo on 29th OR considering we already have id_fixing '2' "*full allocated*"

**EDIT**

I have to get the value [qtt_terminal_loaded] that is in __tt_Freight_Product and "allocate" it on table Product, column qtt_terminal. But, I have to distribute __tt_Freight_Product.qtt_terminal_loaded into one or more "id_fixing", in the order that they appear (id_fixing = 1 and 2).

That way, as in the example data, in 25th, we have qtt_terminal_loaded equals to 200,000. So, this 200,00, is the amount that I am able to distribute into multiple id_fixing. But, id_fixing = 1, has a "balance" of 300,00 "to receive" from qtt_terminal_loaded (which is determined by the column "qtt_fixing". qtt_terminal, the column that I am trying to update, can't be more than qtt_fixing. Never. That way, on 26th, if we sum previous qtt_terminal_loaded, we would get 400,00. But first id_fixing is just 300,000. So, from that day on, I start to allocate into id_fixing = 2. In this case, 100,000 on that day.

Was I clear? I'm trying to do my best to explain.

**END EDIT**

Image containing sample output:
[image]

Scripts containing table creations and example data:

```
-- CREATE sample "__tt_Freight_Product"
IF object_id('tempdb..#__tt_Freight_Product') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #__tt_Freight_Product;
END;

SELECT  a.dt_reference_date,
        a.id_contract,
        a.qtt_terminal_loaded
INTO    #__tt_Freight_Product
FROM    ( VALUES ( '2015-02-25', '0000006-t12', 200000),
        ( '2015-02-26', '0000006-t12', 200000),
        ( '2015-02-28', '0000006-t12', 100000) ) a ( dt_reference_date, id_contract, qtt_terminal_loaded );

-- CREATE sample "Product"
IF object_id('tempdb..#Product') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #Product;
END;

SELECT  a.dt_reference_date,
        a.id_contract,
        a.id_fixing,
        a.qtt_fixing,
        a.qtt_terminal
INTO    #Product
FROM    ( VALUES ( '2015-02-24', '0000006-t12', 1, 300000, 0),
        ( '2015-02-25', '0000006-t12', 1, 300000, 0),
        ( '2015-02-26', '0000006-t12', 1, 300000, 0),
        ( '2015-02-27', '0000006-t12', 1, 300000, 0),
        ( '2015-02-28', '0000006-t12', 1, 300000, 0),
        ( '2015-02-29', '0000006-t12', 1, 300000, 0),
        ( '2015-02-24', '0000006-t12', 2, 200000, 0),
        ( '2015-02-25', '0000006-t12', 2, 200000, 0),
        ( '2015-02-26', '0000006-t12', 2, 200000, 0),
        ( '2015-02-27', '0000006-t12', 2, 200000, 0),
        ( '2015-02-28', '0000006-t12', 2, 200000, 0),
        ( '2015-02-29', '0000006-t12', 2, 200000, 0) ) a ( dt_reference_date, id_contract, id_fixing, qtt_fixing, qtt_terminal );
```

Any ideas?

Comment: My comment would the same here as I made on sqlservercentral. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1671044-3412-1.aspx

Comment: I'm very happy to know you're willing to help. I've gotta go for a while, but once I get to work again, I'll be glad to do what you've instructed me.

Comment: OK cool. Now we have some data to work with. What is the question? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @SeanLange I need to update the product table, column "qtt_terminal". The desired output is in the attached image on the question.

Comment: Any formula on how to calculate qtt_terminal for id_fixing = "1" and id_fixing = "2"?. I don't see the logic you are applying

Comment: The values in your output don't make any sense. Suddenly id_contract starts incrementing the last character and qtt_terminal...what is the logic there?

Comment: @SeanLange the only thing that has to be updated is table Product, column qtt_terminal.

Comment: @user3281440 See updated question text.

Comment: OK great. What is the logic. There doesn't appear to be any correlation here. Considering id_fixing 1 why is qtt_terminal supposed to change to 200,00 on the 25th? Maybe that is the reference date? But if so, why does it then increase to 300,00 the next day? There is something missing in your explanation here.

Comment: @SeanLange plase, check if I was clear on my edit section of the question.

Comment: This looks like some sort of running total with really bad table structures under it. Can you confirm which version of sql server you are using?

Comment: Marco you wasn't clear, i don t see any logic. If yes, please describe a formula in pseudo code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be some denormalization in your data model. The same qtt_fixing value seems to be repeated for all occurrences of the same id_contract and id_fixing, right? Assuming that's guaranteed, here's a possible solution:

```
with f as
(
  select *,
    sum(qtt_terminal_loaded) over(partition by id_contract
                                  order by dt_reference_date
                                  rows unbounded preceding) as runsum
  from #__tt_freight_product
),
p as
(
  select *,
    sum(qtt_fixing) over(partition by id_contract, dt_reference_date
                         order by id_fixing
                         rows unbounded preceding) as runsum
  from #product
)
update p
  set qtt_terminal =
    case
      when f.runsum >= p.runsum then p.qtt_fixing
      when p.runsum - p.qtt_fixing < f.runsum then f.runsum - (p.runsum - p.qtt_fixing)
      else 0
    end
from p
  outer apply (select top (1) *
               from f
               where f.id_contract = p.id_contract
                 and f.dt_reference_date <= p.dt_reference_date
               order by f.dt_reference_date desc) as f;

select *
from #product;
```

Note that the solution is not optimized at all. I provide it just so that you can study the logic. A few more steps would be required to optimize it, like storing intermediate results in temporary tables and indexing them.
Also, this solution uses aggregate window functions with a frame--a feature that was introduced in SQL Server 2012. If you're using an older version, you would probably be better off using an iterative solution.

Cheers,
Itzik

Comment: Unfortunately, wrong. This is a snapshot of a id_fixing over the time. I can guarantee that my modeling is all right.  Thank you anyway. I'm using SQL Server 2014

Comment: @MarcoAlves, Seems like Itzik solved the problem for your modeling.  Do you still have a problem with the result?

Comment: @JeffModen I will test and return today